# How do I check each word of a string with each word of other string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, sentiment-analysis

[image]
This is what I have as reference and I want to check my list with this list and score then based on the sum of POS and NEG

[image] 
I'm new to python so this might be easy. I'm calculating sentiment score of strings with reference to dataset which has list of words with +ve and -ve score. So i want to add +ve score and subtract -ve score if I find the word from  test set in reference dataset. For that I would have to access each word from test string and check with reference dataset.
This is my code:

```py
for i in range(0,29):
    my_string = processed[i]
    for word in my_string.split():
        for j in range(0,3013):
            senti_words=senti['LIST_OF_WORDS'].iloc[j,4]
            if  word in senti_words:
               pos=senti['LIST_OF_WORDS'].iloc[j,2]
               neg=senti['LIST_OF_WORDS'].iloc[j,3]
               sentiment=pos-neg
               a=a.append(sentiment)
```

Comment: The if condition is wrongly formatted

Comment: @tawab_shakeel Any suggestions would be  appreciated  Thanks

Comment: kindly add sample data and desired results

Comment: I have edit the code in your question there was syntax error

Comment: What else statement should I apply to skip non matching words?

Comment: you should add sample dataframe with desired output otherwise no one would be able to answer your question correctly

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: kindly follow the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add code not images ,no one can copy data from image

Answer (score 0):

I can see Indentation error after the if block, I don't have the values for senti to try, so try this.

```
for i in range(0,29):
    my_string = processed[i]
    for word in my_string.split():
        for j in range(0,3013):
            senti_words=senti['LIST_OF_WORDS'].iloc[j,4]
            if  word in senti_words:
                pos=senti['LIST_OF_WORDS'].iloc[j,2]
                neg=senti['LIST_OF_WORDS'].iloc[j,3]
                sentiment=pos-neg
                a=a.append(sentiment)
```